# ASP.NET WebDeploy and Code Behind Files

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, webdeploy

I'm using MS WebDeploy out of Visual Studio 2010 to deploy a ASP.NET 2.0 web forms site.  In my source project I have a master page (`admin.master`) with a code-behind (`admin.master.cs`).

Following a successful build and deploy on the target site I have:

```
\bin\myapp.dll
\admin\admin.master
```

But no admin.master.cs

However I'm not expecting this as I thought the code-behind would now be in the myapp.dll?

When I fire up the site I get the following error:

```
The file '/admin/admin.master.cs' does not exist.
Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="admin.master.cs" Inherits="admin" %>
```

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Many thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a website or web application?

`CodeFile="admin.master.cs"` would indicate that it's a website, and in that case you would need to include the code behind files.

Seems odd that when you deploy it builds the dll's and removes the code behind files though.

To deploy a website, you can simply use "Copy Web Site".

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I needed to build it as a Web Site not a Web Application - and Web Deploy only works with Web Apps :(

Comment: To deploy websites, just use "copy web site"